# Swagger Java ApiModelProperty hidden by default

Tags: java, swagger

Is it possible to hide all properties not marked by `@ApiModelProperty`?

For example I have a class `Entity` and `Test`

```
public class Entity {
    public Integer id;
}

@ApiModel("Class Test")
public class Test extends Entity {
    public Integer value;
}
```

I don't have access to `Entity` it's from persistence library, so I cannot modify it. How can I hide `id` property?